# In systemd using Restart=on-failure and ExecCondition

Tags: systemd

It seems Restart=on-failure do not work if ExecCondition fails, which according to documentation is probably due to systemd not marking the unit as failed.
However, I would like to restart the unit after a timer if it fails the condition,
I am aware that I could simply use ExecPreStart, but that would also clutter the logs.
Is there a good solution, or is ExecPreStart the way?